# Vim folding for GISDK

Tags: vim, folding

GISDK (TransCAD) macros are structured as follows:

```
Macro "MacroName" (options...)
    ... do stuff ...
EndMacro
```

I'm trying to write a vim syntax file that will fold these macros, ideally showing the macro name, like:

```
+-- x lines: MacroName---------------------
```

From what I've picked up online, I'm starting with

```
syn region SynFoldMacro 
        \ start=/Macro/
        \ end=/EndMacro\n/
        \ fold transparent
```

But this doesn't get the macro name, and it also comes out looking like this:

```
Macro "MacroOne" (options...)
    ... do stuff ...
+-- 14 lines: EndMacro ------------

Macro "MacroThree" (options...)
     ... do other stuff....
+-- 23 lines: EndMacro ------------
```

So `MacroTwo` got folded inside the end of `MacroOne`.

Comment: Just an unhelpful comment here, but I thought I'd share. I had folding enabled for years. When I started writing software professionally, I found the first thing I'd do when I opened a file was hit `zi` so I disabled folding. It just got in my way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't always use it. But sometimes I'm dealing with people that write 3000 line scripts (not me). Being able to see what is going on in these scripts without scrolling for four minutes is useful to me.